# Can anyone explain me please what this terms mean one by one and more explicitly like (1- x/K) and mx/b+x2

Tags: mathematical-modeling

Actually it's a prey-predator model (for specifically, Bogdanov–Takens bifurcation of a Holling IV prey–predator model with constant-effort harvesting). Please help me to understand these terms so that I can explain it and solve it more easily. I really want to get where these terms come from. Or at least understanding (1- x/K) and mx/b+x2 terms will be enough for me . I searched a lot but couldn't find the explicit explanation. What does the (1-x/K) - (mx)/(b+x^2) mean in the equation:
x'= r1x(1-x/K) - (mx)/(b+x^2)- c1x .
I know that it's a rate of change of x during the time period (x as a prey in this particular equation) and r1x is the initial population of prey and the rest of the terms effect to change of x. But I'm trying to figure out what are they and how did we write it. Where did they come from. Just wanted to know the meaning of them. That's all

Thanks in advance
[Prey-predator model with Leslie-Gower and Holling IV schemes with constant-effort harvesting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMX2v.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of linking to images.  Also, please [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) - things like what are your own thoughts?  Where is this coming from?  What's your background with mathematical modeling?  In general, see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Ok Sir. Sorry for the that. Thank you so much for informing me. I will be more careful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with this particular model so I won't be able to give you a perfectly detailed answer, but here is some insight.

It is helpful to understand the [Logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#In_ecology:_modeling_population_growth) in the context of population growth. It is of the form

$\frac{dP}{dt} = rP(1-\frac{P}{K})$.

This is a model for a population, $P$, with growth at a rate $r$ but with a maximum population $K$.

So we can see, in your model, that each equation has a term like this. $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the prey and predator population growth rates, the prey has a carrying capacity of $K$ while the predator has one of $sx$ (i.e. the more prey that exist, the more food there is to support a larger predator population).

The term $\frac{mx}{b+x^2}y$ causes the prey population to decrease and seems to take into account the fact that prey are hunted and killed off by predators with each predator killing at a rate of $\frac{mx}{b+x^2}$.

The last two terms decrease each population at a rate equal to a constant times their population. This probably accounts from death due to old age or being hunted by some third group.

Comment: Appreciate you so much for the explanation. It was useful and something started to shape on my mind. But Still have a question stuck on my mind why do we divide The growth rate and squared of initial prey population by K carrying capacity? If you have any idea please let me know I will be really appreciate. Thanks in advance

Comment: @SülgünRejepova I don't fully understand your question. In the logistic model we have a term like $(1-P/K))$ because it forces an upper limit of $P=K$. If you are asking why the term $\frac{mx}{b+x^2}$ shows up in front of $y$ instead of some other function, I cannot say.

Comment: OK I got.  If I find the answer I will share it here. Thanks much for help and for taking your time.